# Scrape all visible text from a web page

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, capybara, nokogiri

Is there an easy way to parse an HTML page to just get the text that is visible to the user?
I want to get rid of all the tags, links, JavaScript and return the text content that was on the page.

I just want to store the info and come back to it later but use it in a search.

Have tried Nokogiri and Capybara/Poltergeist

```
doc.css('body').text
```

But that gives me all sorts of JavaScript and rubbish that I'd rather not see.

Is there a way just to strip the bits of text and batch them into a string whilst ignoring all the 'code'?

Comment: Do you want the text AFTER CSS and JavaScript have had a chance to hide/move text, or do you want the text that would display if JavaScript and CSS were not enabled?

Comment: Only looking to take the visible text, before js is fine. 
Found the method using capybara which does the job elegantly and simply. 
Would be really helpful to be able to do this with Nokogiri / Mechanize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy, actually.

Using Capybara (and PhantomJS in my case, though I don't think it matters)

```
    @session.visit url
    # Grab the text from the page
    @session.text
    # Grab the page title
    @session.title
```

Does the job perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the text that a real user gets, then simulate a real user. One way is to use Watir-Webdriver using something like PhantomJS, for example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
browser.goto 'https://google.com'
puts browser.body.text
```

Of course, for this to work (PhantomJS to be specific) you need to download the file for the appropriate JS ([PhantomJS Downloads](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)) and place it in your PATH.

The reason why you're getting all this is that Nokogiri doesn't act like a real user, it just scrapes and parses the HTML document which may contain a bunch of embedded HTML and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) with good results.

Sanitize gives you a `clean` method, that allows you to specify [configuration](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize#configuration).

You can choose the configuration that works best in your case.

There is a [demo](https://sanitize.herokuapp.com) and a [comparison](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/blob/master/COMPARISON.md) available for you to check.